# javascript singleton pattern - problem in creating different instances

Tags: javascript, singleton, multiple-instances

I have a problem in creating instances/objects from a javascript class that I have written. Can you please check the code and see the output which is at the bottom of the code.

Thanks in advance...
Regards.

```
//MARKER MANAGER CLASS
            var MarkerManager = (function(){

                var arr = [];
                var arrName = [];
                var counter = 0;

                var MarkerManager = function (args){

                    arr = [];
                    arrName = [];
                    counter = 0;            

                    return {
                        addMarker: addMarker,
                        getMarker: getMarker,
                        getIndex: getIndex
                    }

                };

                function getIndex(){
                    return counter;
                }

                function addMarker(marker){
                    arrName[counter] = marker.name;
                    arr[counter] = marker;
                    counter++;
                }

                function getMarkerNameList(){
                    return arrName;
                }

                function getMarker(li_name){
                    var markerIndex = arrName.indexOf(li_name);         
                    return  arr[markerIndex];
                }



                /*var instance;

                var _static = {

                    name: 'manager',

                    getInstance: function (args){

                        if(instance === undefined){
                            instance = new MarkerManager(args)
                        }

                        return instance;

                    }               

                };

                return _static;
                */

                return function (args){

                    var manager = new MarkerManager(args);
                    return manager;

                }

            })();


            var marker1 = new Marker({name:'test0', lat:3 ,  lng:5, isDraggable:true, iconType:'red' });
            var marker2 = new Marker({name:'test1', lat:33 , lng:55, isDraggable:true, iconType:'red' });
            var marker3 = new Marker({name:'test2', lat:44 , lng:99, isDraggable:true, iconType:'red' });
            var marker4 = new Marker({name:'test3', lat:55 , lng:77, isDraggable:true, iconType:'red' });
            var marker5 = new Marker({name:'test4', lat:88 , lng:65, isDraggable:true, iconType:'red' });

            var manager  = new MarkerManager({test:'test2'}); //MarkerManager.getInstance({map:'testtt'});//
            var manager2 = new MarkerManager({test:'test1'});

            manager.addMarker(marker1);
            manager.addMarker(marker2);
            manager.addMarker(marker3);

            manager2.addMarker(marker4);
            manager2.addMarker(marker5);

            alert(manager.getMarkerNameList());     
            alert(manager2.getMarkerNameList());

        //output is "test0,test1,test2,test3,test4" for both manager objects. How can I separate them
```

Comment: You have two definitions of MarkerManager and no definitions of Marker.  Also, please state what the problem is that you want help with.

Comment: What does the title of your post mean? If you're trying to use a singleton pattern why are you also trying to create different instances?

Comment: @nnnnn because what I have written is not creating different instances.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did not want to mess up the code, it was already too long. It simply shows and asks what I need. I think Ghostoy understood what I need. I will comment once I try.  PS: Please be easy with people who need help, I found both of your language a little offensive.Thanks anyway to both of you.

Comment: @user403295 - offensive?  That's odd.  You gave a code example that makes no sense because there's no Marker object defined.  I asked you to fix that.  Then, I told you I didn't understand what the question or problem was.  If you don't care to clarify the question, then most people won't be able to help.  If you already got the help you need, then you can ignore the rest of us who could have helped if we understood the problem and code.  Not sure why you thought that was offensive.  Check my record - I've helped hundreds in only a few weeks.

Comment: @jfriend00  just assume that I am trying to create 2 different managers and keep objects in them. As output in the answer shows that the objects added in different managers were somehow merged but I wanted to handle them separately in the manager objects that I have create. That was my problem. I thought it was clear enough. Ghostoy's answer was correct. It is working now. I will put the full code including Marker class to make it clear as you asked. Thanks for your replies and time. Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move all the variables & functions needed by the manager to the constructor function. Or the MarkerManagers will share the same variables & functions together.

```
        var MarkerManager = (function(){
            return function (args){

                var arr = [];
                var arrName = [];
                var counter = 0;

                var MarkerManager = function (args){

                    arr = [];
                    arrName = [];
                    counter = 0;            

                    return {
                        addMarker: addMarker,
                        getMarker: getMarker,
                        getIndex: getIndex
                    }

                };

                function getIndex(){
                    return counter;
                }

                function addMarker(marker){
                    arrName[counter] = marker.name;
                    arr[counter] = marker;
                    counter++;
                }

                function getMarkerNameList(){
                    return arrName;
                }

                function getMarker(li_name){
                    var markerIndex = arrName.indexOf(li_name);         
                    return  arr[markerIndex];
                }


                var manager = new MarkerManager(args);
                return manager;

            }

        })();
```